# How to search multiline var for a string in case statement?

Tags: regex, ksh

I have a variable called `RESPONSE` which hold the output of another command - it will have multiple lines of text

I am trying to do a case statement which will perform some action if either of two strings is found within that `RESPONSE` variable

Here's my attempt:

```
   case ${RESPONSE} in 
    "-20002") echo "found -20002"
    ;;
    "-20001") echo "found -20001"
    ;;
   esac
```

I am getting neither output when the RESPONSE has -20001 inside of it, for example.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect I need to set some sort of multiline option but how?

Comment: Why don't you just use `grep`?

Comment: case match expession are pretty literal. Try changing to `"*-20002*"` ... etc. The `-` may also be causing a problem. Get match to work without that first, the experiment with different quoting, `\-`, `[-]`, `[\-]` (just guessing there ; -) ). If you're desparate, maybe your shell supports `$"ANSI-String"` and `$'ANSI-String'` ?  Good luck.

Comment: nope none of those are working. how do i use grep in a if? I tried and I keep getting this output "grep can't open ####" for every text in RESPONSE where #### = each word

Comment: consider editing your question to include a small sample of your multi-line output that is going into RESPONSE. Right now, too many possibilities cloud providing a quick answer to your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more experimenting with small test cases. I'm surprized that enclosing the case match target in dbl-quotes affected the results, but .... here you go.

```
cat RESPONSE.txt
some stuff
-20002
more stuff

RESP=$(< RESPONSE.txt) 

case $RESP in 
 # bad! "*-20002*" ) echo found 20002 ;; 
 *-20002* ) echo found 20002 ;; 
 # bad! "*-20004*" ) echo found 20004 ;; 
 *-20004* ) echo found 20004 ;; 
  * ) echo no match ;;
esac
```

**output**

```
found 20002
```

It also works the same with

```
case "$RESP" in ....
```

---

@ajay says

Note - The dbl-quote is probably not working because it is causing * to lose its special meaning

---

I agree with this. Not sure why it was rejected as an edit. No time to worry about it though.

IHTH

Comment: Thanks @ajay for your attempt to improve my answer. Not sure why it was rejected as an edit. Good luck.